# Sequence convergence property proof check.

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Question: Let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ be convergent sequences with $a_n \Rightarrow L$ and $b_n \Rightarrow M$ as $n \Rightarrow \infty$.

Prove that if $M \neq 0$, then $\frac{a_n}{b_n} \Rightarrow \frac{L}{M}$ \

My solution:

WTS:

(1) $\exists L \in \mathbb R, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N_1 > 0$, such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, if $n > N_1$, then $|a_n - L| < \frac{\epsilon}{|M-L|}$

(2) $\exists M \in \mathbb R, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N_2 > 0$, such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, if $n > N_2$, then $|b_n - M| < \frac{\epsilon}{|M-L|}$

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary

Choose N = max($N_1, N_2$)

Suppose $n > N$, then

$$|\frac{a_n}{b_n} - \frac{L}{M}| = |a_nM - Lb_n| \text{ by common factors}$$

$$= |a_nM - LM + LM - Lb_n| = |M(a_n - L) - L(b_n - M)| \text{ by algebra}$$

$$\leq |M(a_n - L)| - |L(b_n - M)| \text{ By triangle  inequality}$$

$$< |M - L| \frac{\epsilon}{|M-L|} \text{ by given info}$$

$$= \epsilon$$

Is this correct? Thx.

L = M is a counter example as pointed out so I made a second attempt.

---

## SECOND SOLUTION:

WTS:

let K := sup($|b_n|$)

(1) $\exists L \in \mathbb R, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N_1 > 0$, such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, if $n > N_1$, then $|a_n - L| < \frac{|K|\epsilon}{2}$

(2) $\exists M \in \mathbb R, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N_2 > 0$, such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, if $n > N_2$, then $|b_n - M| < \frac{|KM|}{2|L|}\epsilon$

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary

Choose N = max($N_1, N_2$)

Suppose $n > N$, then

$$|\frac{a_n}{b_n} - \frac{L}{M}| = \bigg|\frac{a_nM - Lb_n}{b_nM}\bigg| $$

$$= \bigg|\frac{M(a_n - L) + L(M - b_n)}{|b_nM|}\bigg| \text{ by algebra}$$

$$\leq \frac{|M(a_n - L)| + |L(M - b_n)|}{|b_nM|} \text{ By triangle  inequality}$$

$$= \frac{|a_n - L|}{|b_n|} + \frac{L|b_n - M|}{|b_nM|}$$

$$< |K|\frac{\epsilon}{2|K|} + |K|\frac{\epsilon |L||M|}{2|L||K||M|}$$

$$= \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$$ As required.

Comment: My issue is with $|\frac{a_n}{b_n} - \frac{L}{M}| = |a_nM - Lb_n|$. The right side should be divided by $|b_n * M|$ for the equality to hold. However, $b_n$ is consistently changing with n. I believe this proof can be found in the first part of chapter 3 in Baby Rudin.

Comment: I was thinking that. With that below it makes it so complicated so I wondered cant I just say I used common factors to get rid of it? Because isn't that what you do for PFD or even finding an unknown? I unno. I have no idea how to do if that stays though.

Comment: Baby Rudin Chapter 3 has the solution.

Comment: What if we have  $L=M$?

Comment: How about now?  @ΘΣΦGenSan

Comment: Warning ! Triangle inequality doesn't allow you to write $|a-b|\le|a|-|b|$

Comment: :o Thank you. Didnt know that

Comment: Fixed the 2nd one's triangle inequality, not the first one.